# Como fazer uma Linha aumentar a altura automaticamente css javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, html5, progress-bar, height

Boa noite, gente eu estou com o seguinte problema, no layout que estou montando tem varias linhas em lugares diferentes durante o decorrer da pagina, o cliente quer que essas linhas apareçam e vão crescendo vindo de direções diferentes, inicialmente eu fiz uma dessas linhas usando o "progress" do html5, porém so consigo fazer isso quando é para aumentar a largura, quando a linha esta na vertical tenho problemas, tentei usar o transform rotate porem não ficou bom pois mesmo usando o rotate ela ainda ocupa o tamanho lateral na tela, enfim eu queria outras formas de fazer essa linha aumentar, que seja maleavel tanto eu posso aumentar a largura quanto a altura sem prejudicar o layout, estou fazendo assim por enquanto, assim ta com o rotate:

```
<progress id="barra1" class='custom' max='100' value='0' data-value=''></progress>

<script>
var $progress = document.querySelector('#barra1'), // Pegando o elemento
MAXIMUM   = $progress.max;                      // Pegando o valor máximo: 
100

/* Aumentando o valor a cada 1 segundo... */
var interval = setInterval(function(){
$progress.value++;
if($progress.value >= MAXIMUM)
clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
</script>

.custom {
background-color: #dc853d;
width: 800px;
height: 1px;
transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona melhor com JQuery:

```
<div>
    <hr id="linha" class="borda-p">
</div>

ou dessa forma

<div>
    <hr id="linha2" class="borda-p-ja-vertical">
</div>

<style>
    .borda-p{
        border: #000 thin solid;
        width: 0;
    }
    .borda-p-ja-vertical{
        border: #000 thin solid;
        width: 0; 
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .aumenta-vertical{
        transition: ease-out all;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;            
        transition-duration: 4s;
        width: 100%;            
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //ao terminar de carregar a pagina da o efeito, mas no jsfiddle nao
    //da pra visualizar, porque usa ajax, então a página já foi carregada
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        $('#linha').addClass('aumenta-vertical');
        $('#linha2').addClass('aumenta-vertical');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: gostei muito da resposta, mas tem algo que não ta funcionando, quer dizer quando eu coloco no inspecionar retiro e coloco o width funciona perfeitamente, mas ao carregar a pagina normal a linha ja aparece com 100%

Comment: Tenta colocar `width="0%"` em vez de apenas `0`, mas como diz o ditado do programador... na minha máquina funcionou, hehe. Ahh, uma super dica, em vez de teclar `F5` pra atualizar a página, tecle `ctrl+F5`, muitas alterações em arquivos dependentes como `css` ou `js`, nem sempre atualizam só no `F5` normal.

Comment: entendo rs, poxa eu gostei da maneira usando o transition mas realmente não ta indo, olha aqui no js fidle https://jsfiddle.net/nmLdtsmy/1/

Comment: já ta aparecendo 100%, so se eu tirar e colocar o width no inspecionar ai ele funciona sabe

Comment: Cara, percebi que no meu código que testei, não tava exatamente igual, vou atualizar minha resposta pra você, desculpa aí.

Comment: agora sim amigo rs muito bom adorei o resultado do seu exemplo rs alguma maneira de fazer para acompanhar a barra de scroll? porque dessa maneira apesar de ser bem mais simples do que o modo que eu estava fazendo mas se a linha tiver abaixo na pagina o efeito pode não ser percebido, mas já ajudou bastante viu

Comment: Que bom que ajudei, tem uns caras na comunidade que só botam defeito, além de não ajudar. Bem.. para que acompanhe a **rolagem** da página, que eu saiba, só usando no css o `position:fixed` ai, se por exemplo, você for colocar uma linha do lado direito da página, adicione um `right: 5px`, se for no topo, um `top: 0px` e assim por diante.